# Evaluating calibration accuracy of stereo vision system

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I have developed a Structured Light Scanning system. Until now I have used checker board and Matlab for calibrating without any issues. Recently, I have started using OpenCV calibration module with asymmetric circles grid for calibration. Calibration pattern was printed and pasted on a flat glass panel. The circle centres’ were measured with a profile projector and that data is used for calibration.

**Calibration results:**

Total Views: 18 covering the entire FoV of camera.

Re-projection error: Cam1: 0.27, Cam2: 0.08; Cam2 is actually a projector but that doesn’t matter here.

Stereo Calibration RMS: 0.457 (isn’t it slightly high?)

But the point cloud generated is not as good as expected. A flat board was captured but you can see that the point cloud is not exactly flat. Point cloud generation is fine, I know this from the fact that with Checkered board+Matlab calibration module, the point cloud is as expected. Given that HQ plate was used and reproj errors are low, I’m unable to determine what is causing this issue. Is it the OpenCV calib module or any other issue?

[image]

Comment: If you compare the intrinsic matrices between Matlab and OpenCV, is there  a big difference? Also, how did you reconstruct your point cloud (triangulation, dense matching, etc.)?

Comment: Calibration seems fine, there is not much difference between Matlab and OpenCV intrinsic matrices. I think the problem is with the triangulation function in OpenCV. It has been resolved, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how did you solve your problem. Maybe you can add your triangulation method as an answer?